# Does Google Nest Hub support WebRTC?

Tags: webrtc, google-assistant-sdk, google-home, google-assist-api

I am implementing a camera device and thinking using WebRTC as the video/audio streaming protocol with the app. And I would like to stream the video/audio to Google Nest Hub. But from all the documents I can find, I didn't find any information that is related to WebRTC? So, I am curious if Google Nest Hub or Chromecast supports WebRTC or not? If yes, where can I find the related sample or document?

Comment: The public documentation does not have any references to WebRTC.

Answer (score 0):

Google Nest Hub now supports WebRTC protocol. More information in regards to
this can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/traits/device/camera-live-stream#generatewebrtcstream). Currently Chromecast does not support WebRTC, but we are constantly working on improving the capabilities of our ecosystem